# NAS via HDD connected to PC or HDD connected to the router

Tags: hard-drive, router, usb, performance, nas

### Hardware I am working with

- [Netgear Nighthawk AC1900 (R7000)](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/datasheet/en/R7000.pdf) (**USB 3.0**; running stock firmware, but can run Tomato if needed)
- [Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex Desk 2 TB **USB 3.0** External Hard Drive](https://sites.google.com/site/bestexternalharddrivesv/best-deal-seagate-freeagent-goflex-desk-2-tb-usb-3-0-external-hard-drive-stac2000106) (MPN: STAC2000106, UPC: 763649035368)
- [Lenovo V570 Core i5 2410M](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0%2c2817%2c2387552%2c00.asp?tab=Specs) (**USB 2.0 only**)

  > ***Note:***
  >   *The Lenovo V570 notebook is connected to the Netgear R7000 router via ethernet cord. **The notebook will always be powered on and never be moved from its position.***

I would like to access the 2TB Seagate drive from **within** and **outside** the network. I am also considering running [Syncany](https://github.com/syncany/syncany) as my self-hosted syncing platform.

---

### My question

Would it be better to:

> **a)** plug the Seagate HDD *directly* into the router?
>
> -=OR=-
>
> **b)** plug the Seagate HDD into the laptop (which is in turn plugged into the router)?

I am asking in terms of **performance**, **pros**, and **cons**. I'm aware of general differences between using a laptop and router. ***Please compare read/write speed values based on component chipsets.***

Comment: Is the laptop stationary or mobile? I'd just go with **b** but keep a mirror backup at home if it's mobile. It's just a lot simpler.

Comment: The laptop is stationary.

Comment: HDD directly to Router

Comment: In my experience external hard drives are extremely unreliable and have a high rate of failure. You are also creating a single point of failure as you likely only have one drive. To do a NAS properly you should get a dedicated NAS solution. My experience has been with Synology and it has been the optimal way to go. You connect via ethernet instead of USB and you can get a two drive box so that you can set up a raid, that way if a drive goes bad, the raid can recover the data. You can use the Seagate as a back up device to the NAS box.

Comment: Why would people downvote without any mention of an issue with the question?

Comment: @AMR, so you find USB the point of failure? Meaning either of my intended solutions would be substandard?

Comment: Router-hosted NAS services have always had issues with CPU-limited performance. Personally I'd go hardcore and run an iSCSI or USBoIP target on the router, use that to mount the HDD on the laptop, and perform the actual NAS'ing on the laptop. That way the router doesn't have to handle the (relatively) CPU intensive SMB/NFS/AFS/etc.

Comment: @Raj. I wasn't trying to say that USB is your point of failure. Anecdotally I have found that External USB HDD's are highly prone to catastrophic failure. I have four Western Digital drives sitting in a cupboard that all failed and you can no longer access any of the data and are bricked as they cannot even be reformatted. I tried Seagate, and use it to back up my NAS, but while I can still access the data, the backup no longer goes to completion, even though I have reformatted the drive on a number of occasions. So personally I have been burned.

Comment: My mention of a single point of failure has to do with the fact that you have a single drive. If you have even a two disk NAS set up as a RAID, the if one of the drives goes bad, you can swap in another and the raid should be able to recover, And while relying on RAID alone is not advisable, as you should also back up your data as well. I guess the real question you have to ask yourself is how valuable is your data to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect the hard drive to the router:

- Storage performance (read/write speeds) may be limited by the CPU power of the router. For your router, this appears to be about 60MB/s read and 35MB/s write ([review](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-reviews/32239-ac1900-first-look-netgear-r7000-a-asus-rt-ac68u?showall=&start=1)).
- You will be able to connect using only the protocols supported by your router
- You won't need to install or manage any server software on your laptop
- Netgear's proprietary software could add value (using ReadyCloud to configure external access)

If you connect the hard drive to your laptop:

- Storage access will consume CPU cycles on your laptop, but access to the storage will be as fast as the device or USB 2.0 connection allows, which is 30 MB/s read, 15 MB/s write ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive#Second_generation))
- You can configure whatever services you would like for the device (SMB, FTP, etc)
- You lose a USB port on your laptop

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting it to the router:

- The NAS will be accessible 24/7
- You're only bottleneck is the routers speed whereas if it was connected to the laptop, the laptop's NIC speed would also be a factor
- The router is designed to shave high volume of data whereas the laptop isn't
- Most routers can configure the NAS via it's web interface

---

If you're connecting to the laptop:

- The laptop would have to be on 24/7 which it isn't designed to do
- If the laptop needs to be restarted, the NAS is unalienable for that time
- More complicated to manage across devices
- Need to share your computer login details to gain access to it which poses a security risk

Answer (score -1):

- **a)** means it might have performance issues as usb can interfere with wireless
- **b)** this will work if you dont mind slower speed, if you are using wireless for the other devices, its baiscly as fast as wireless goes anyway

Comment: USB cannot interfere with wireless

Comment: well intel says otherwise http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-frequency-interference-paper.html

Comment: You don't seem to have read or understood the paper you are referring to. Their research shows no real world impact in the B/G band 2.4Ghz and no interference whatsoever in the A/AC band at 5Ghz. And if you believe the (broken) signal readouts from Intel's own wireless cards, even at 2.4Ghz it's four times weaker than undetectable.